# Update database if Post value is not null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to update the table Users only if the $_POST[*value*] is not null. If it is null, the value already in the column should remain.

```
$query = "UPDATE `Users` 
SET FirstName = COALESCE(:firstName, FirstName), LastName = ISNULL(:lastName, LastName), City = :city, State = :state WHERE Email = :email";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':firstName', $firstName);
$stmt->bindValue(':lastName', $lastName);
$stmt->bindValue(':city', $city);
$stmt->bindValue(':state', $state);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

I tried COALESCE for the column FirstName and ISNULL for the LastName. COALESCE replaces my value with blank(NULL) which is exactly that opposite of what I want accomplished and ISNULL doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean `COALESCE` is replacing the FirstName with a blank (''), then try using `NULLIF`:

```
UPDATE `Users` 
SET FirstName = COALESCE(NULLIF(:firstName,''), FirstName) ...
```

I'm assuming the POST is posting a blank.

Good luck.

Comment: Same issue. You are assuming correct. The input box ($_POST['firstName']) is taken into variable $firstName and when I hit sumbit, if the value in firstName is blank, the database updates a blank.

Comment: @user1964239 -- did you see my edit -- I originally accidently used IFNULL but changed it to NULLIF.  Hope that helped!

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much.. I really thought COALESCE would work by itself. If its not too much could you briefly explain why it didn't work?

Comment: @user1964239 -- np, COALESCE only checks for NULLs, not blanks.  That's where you need to use something like NULLIF.  Best of luck.

Comment: oh, got it. All this time I thought when we Post blanks it actually posts NULL but guess not. Thanks once again.

Comment: Great, the best answer!!